# jQuery document.ready stops the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I have right now is that when I put the document.ready code wrapping my script it stopps working.
I know I can simply not use it, because I only call the script in the end of my HTML, but I want to know why it is breaking my code.
PS: I have already added jQuery
Code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.clicker').click(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('clicker'))
            {
                var row_index = $(this).parents('tr').index();
                $(this).text('Cancelar');
                $(this).attr('class', 'cancelar');
                var index = row_index - 2;
                $(".save:eq("+index+")").css('display', 'inline');
            }
            else 
            {
                $(this).text('Editar');
                $(this).attr('class', 'clicker');
                $('.save').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
//In the end of the html file:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery should be included at the top of the page.

$ is not defined - 
You are trying to run Jquery but is is not defined which is breaking your page - your script failing there when you trying to run your document.ready.

Comment: Ok. I Will try it. But it is still working without this document ready part. Doesent it mean that jquery is already defined?

Comment: @J.Turolla As page is read from the top - part in the document.ready wont be executed as JQ is not defined at this moment and it will fail. Then you are including JQ and all script in js/script.js will run ok as you already included JQ.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work. Looking at my header.html I see I was calling the script.js file before declaring jquery as you said. Thank you

Comment: @J.Turolla no problem